# Getting Oracle Server version

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to get Oracle Server Version installed on a server(not client version) using Powershell command. I am using below command to get the value and getting it successfully, however, it's taking a lot of time to get it so causing performance issue.

```
$SEL='';$se_dir = Get-ChildItem C:\\ -Filter 'inventory.xml' -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | % { $_.FullName }; if (-!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($se_dir))) { foreach ($dir in $se_dir) { if (([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($SEL))) { if (Test-Path $dir) {$SEL = Select-String -Path $dir -Pattern 'OraDb';  if (-! ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($SEL))){ $DB = Select-String -Path $dir -Pattern 'SAVED_WITH';  if (-! ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($DB))){ $version_no=(($DB).ToString()).split('>')[1].split('<')[0] } } else  { ;}  } else { ;} }} } ;  if ( $version -ne ' ' -and -!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($version)) ){$final_string =  ''''  + 'Yes' + '''' + ',' + '''' + 'Oracle Version' + '''' + ':' + '''' + ($version_no).TrimEnd(' ,') + '''' }  else { $final_string = '''' + 'No' + '''' + ',' + '''' + 'Oracle Version' + '''' + ':' + '''' + 'No' + ''''}; write-host $final_string
```

is there any way to get it from regitry ?

Comment: Why not just select from `v$version`?

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but the concern is different. I am scanning the C directory and its taking lot of time. So, I am looking for some alternative solutions.